# Springboot Application working in Tomcat 8.5 but not working when deployed in Tomcat 9.0.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

MainClass

```
package com.example.app;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

In pom.xml added following dependencies...

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

same code when deployed on Tomcat 8.5 works fine. But when deployed on Tomcat 9/10 application does not start.
what else to be added to deploy same in tomcat 9/10.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Tomcat 9 or tomcat 10 makes a huge difference. It simply won't work on Tomcat10 as that is JakartaEE and not JavaEE. Tomcat 9 should just work.